# Calculating the number of starts, by customer using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B','B','B','B','B','B'],
               'Date': ['1/1/2021', '2/1/2021','3/1/2021', '4/1/2021','5/1/2021', '6/1/2021','7/1/2021', '1/1/2021', '2/1/2021','3/1/2021', '4/1/2021','5/1/2021', '6/1/2021','7/1/2021'], 
               'Amt': [0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 10, 10]})
```

df

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the beginning and end date for each, which I think is pretty straight forward (i.e., first time each customer customer and last time, as defined by amt > 0).

What I need help with is calculating the number of new acquisitions, whether it's their first purchase or they've churned for a period and come back. For example, for Customer A the first is Feb-21 and the second would be Apr-21. Moreover, Customer B would be Mar-21 and then again on Jun-21. Both would have two new

The desired output would be:

[image]

I'm just not sure where to start on this one.

Comment: Please include your data as text, not images.

Comment: Here you go, thanks!

Comment: Is the "End" for Customer B Jul-21 or Jun-21? Based on your description it seems like Jun!

Comment: It's Jul-21; the last active month for that customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `shift` trick:

```
df["grp"] = df["Amt"].ne(df["Amt"].shift()).cumsum()
new_df = df[df["Amt"].gt(0)].groupby("Customer").agg(Start=("Date", min), 
                                                     End=("Date", max),
                                                     Reactivation=("grp", "nunique"))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
              Start        End  Reactivation
Customer                                    
A        2021-02-01 2021-04-01             2
B        2021-03-01 2021-07-01             2
```

Answer (score -1):

In this answer I'm assuming your date is monthly frequency `pandas.Timestamps`.  If it is something similar like `pandas.Period` then this solution can be tweaked.

The solution involves grouping on `Customer` then applying a function to create a `pandas.IntervalIndex` for each customer, which holds an interval for each month.  The following function does this, then filters out any intervals corresponds to zero values for `Amt`:

```
def create_intervals(sub_df):
    months = pd.PeriodIndex(sub_df["Date"], freq="M")

    return pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
        months.start_time,
        (months+1).start_time
    )[sub_df["Amt"]>0]
```

Use it like so to get a `pandas.Series`, indexed by customer, whose values are `pandas.IntervalIndex`

```
intervals = df.groupby("Customer").apply(create_intervals)
```

The value of `intervals` will be

```
Customer
A    IntervalIndex([(2021-02-01, 2021-03-01], (2021...
B    IntervalIndex([(2021-03-01, 2021-04-01], (2021...
dtype: object
```

Last step is to import [piso](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and use the union function to combine adjacent intervals in each IntervalIndex, and then finally calculate the number of intervals remaining

```
import piso
intervals.apply(piso.union).apply(len)
```

The result

```
Customer
A    2
B    2
dtype: int64
```

Start and end dates can be calculated with

```
intervals.apply(lambda i: i.left.min())
intervals.apply(lambda i: i.left.max())
```

respectively.  Stitch it together:

```
(
    intervals
    .apply(piso.union)
    .apply(len)
    .rename("Reactivated")
    .reset_index()
    .assign(Start = intervals.apply(lambda i: i.left.min()))
    .assign(End = intervals.apply(lambda i: i.left.max()))
)
```

**note**: I am the creator of piso. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: You're missing the start and end date per customer.